# how to switch to another page as main page in windows phone 7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7

i am making a class timetable app for windows phone 7. i have two views for the timetable. a full view which shows all the classes of the week and the other is day's view in which depending on the day of week its contents are shown. how can i load one of these different pages by default depending on the user's choice in the settings page. i tried using the navigate service in the MainPage class constructor.

```
NavigateService.Navigate(new Uri("/Today.xaml",UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: got my answer. using the OnLoaded event handler did the trick

Answer (score 1):

In the **properties** of **'MainPage.xaml'** go to the **'Events'** tab.
Find the **'Loaded'** event and double click it. You'll find yourself in **'MainPage.xaml.cs'** with a method created as:

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     //Some code may already be written       
}
```

Now depending on the state you saved in your settings page you can have a conditional statement within the **'MainPage_Loaded'** method as:

```
if(condition1)
{
    NavigateService.Navigate(new Uri("/Today.xaml",UriKind.Relative));
}
else if(condition2)
{
    // Navigate to a different Uri
}
```

This will navigate the user directly to the next page.

After that, I believe you'd want the application to exit if back button is pressed and not go to the previous page. For this you'll have to put the following code in the **'Loaded'** method of the page you just navigated to:

```
while (NavigationService.BackStack.Any())
{
    NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
}
```

This clears the BackStack of the application and allows application  to exit if the back button is pressed.